# I can VNC into my PI3, but ssh is not working?

Tags: ssh, vnc

I have been trying to ssh into my Raspberry PI 3 and for some reason I keep getting a "ssh: connect to host *address* port 22: Operation timed out"

I know I am using the correct command to call it because it worked great when I first set it up, and it worked earlier when i was directly next to it. I have checked my setting and SSH is enabled.

I can also currently connect and run the PI through a VNC, so I am 100% certain that it is connected to the internet and responding.

I have no clue what to do at this point and ant help would be appreciated!

Edit:
My output with "netstat -tl" is:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address Foreign Address State 
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:ssh 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 
tcp 0 0 localhost:ipp 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:5900 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 
tcp6 0 0 [::]:ssh [::]:* LISTEN 
tcp6 0 0 localhost:ipp [::]:* LISTEN 
tcp6 0 0 [::]:5900 [::]:* LISTEN
```

Comment: Post the output of `netstat -tl` in your question. Also add the command that you are using to ssh into the Pi.

Comment: i was using" ssh pi@10.21.etc" to ssh into the pi, As far as i can tell it seems to be some network issue with me not being on the local network. But NVC works, so I cannot think of an issue why ssh wouldent

Comment: My output with "netstat -tl" was"Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:ssh             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:ipp           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5900            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 localhost:ipp           [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:5900               [::]:*                  LISTEN  "

Comment: Please give us also the output of `ssh -v pi@10.21.etc`. But please don't put it in the comments, edit your question.

Comment: It seems that you are using ssh command line. You can further diagnose it by using `ssh -v pi@<ip-addr>`. I have added your netstat output to your question.